# Issue passing variables from one section to another PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table

i have this code right here. What it does is: 
First the user have to submit one `index.html` form,and by doing this it means that he have to complete all the inputs with his scores (for example 80/100 achievment). After that the user press the submit button and as you can see i have a `//foreach statement` to display their information on a table..that is working great.. but today i added also a button to convert this table information to document.xls(Excel). Pretty sure i am doing something wrong with passing the php variables from one section to another php section.
Also the `<table>` has to be between `<body>` `</body>` and not like `echo <table>` otherwise the script is not working as far as i can say.

---

**Basically** i want the right way to get the variables `$name` `$score1` `$score2` etc.  from the first php section and place them to the ``` <td> <?php $name = $_SESSION['name']; ?>`` </td> <td> <?php $score = $_SESSION['score']; ?> </td> ```
So this is my code:

```
   <?php session_start();?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
</html>
<body>
<?php


function average(){

$name = $_POST['name'];
$score1 = $_POST['math'];
$score2 = $_POST['chemistry'];
$score3 = $_POST['history'];
$score4 = $_POST['english'];
$score5 = $_POST['language'];
$score6 = $_POST['religious'];
$score7 = $_POST['german'];
$score8 = $_POST['physics'];
$score9 = $_POST['latin'];
$score10 = $_POST['french'];
$score11 = $_POST['music'];

$study = array(
    "Mathimatics"=> $score1,
    "Chemistry"=> $score2,
    "Histroy"=> $score3,
    "English"=> $score4,
    "Language"=> $score5,
    "Religious"=> $score6,
    "German"=> $score7,
    "Physics"=> $score8,
    "Latin"=> $score9,
    "French"=> $score10,
    "Music"=> $score11
);


    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['score1'] = $score1;



    //echo "<div>";
    //echo "<table class=\'tableToExl\'>";
    //echo "    <th>Projects</th>";
    //echo "    <th>Score</th>";

    //foreach ($study as $key=>$values){

    //echo "  <tr>";
    //echo "    <td>$key</td>";
    //echo "    <td>$values</td>";
    //echo "  </tr>";

    //}

}

    average();


?>
 <table class="tableToExl" data-tableName="Test Table 1">
     <th>Projects</th>
     <th>Score</th>
        <tr>
             <!-- For example i placed only the name of the student and the first Project-->
        <td> <?php  $name = $_SESSION['name']; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php  $score = $_SESSION['score']; ?> </td>
       </tr>
</table>

<button class="exportToExcel">Export to XLS</button>

<script>
    $(function() {
       $(".exportToExcel").click(function(e){
        var table = $(this).prev('.tableToExl');
        if(table && table.length){
            var preserveColors = (table.hasClass('table2excel_with_colors') ? true : false);
            $(table).table2excel({
                exclude: ".noExl",
                name: "Excel Document Name",
                filename: "myFileName" + new Date().toISOString().replace(/[\-\:\.]/g, "") + ".xls",
                fileext: ".xls",
                exclude_img: true,
                exclude_links: true,
                exclude_inputs: true,
                preserveColors: preserveColors
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Any advise what i am doing wrong ? thnx

Comment: You haven't actually told us what went wrong when you added this code

Comment: i update my question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<td> <?php  echo $_SESSION['name']; ?> </td>
<td> <?php  echo $_SESSION['score']; ?> </td>
```

Comment: can't believe i missed that one :P you are right but now the script isn't working and don't why .. this is another task, anyway you found what i asked for

Comment: Pleasure to help.  May be the error is from different variable name of `$_SESSION['score']` and `$_SESSION['score1']`.